# Iterate through a list in ACL2

Tags: acl2

```
(defun listmover-fun (l n)
 (if (= n (len l)))
     (last l )
(position n 1)
 listmover-fun (l n+1)
  )
```

Trying to figure out how to iterate through a list in ACL2, I know it can be done in lisp but I can't use those functions. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Iteration in ACL2 is done through recursion. there is no "iteration"